# figsize in matplotlib is not changing the figure size

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

load imports

```
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

read and plot audio

```
filename = 'C:/Users/adil/Desktop/PROJ 2/Udacity-ML-Capstone-master/UrbanSound Dataset sample/audio/103074-7-0-0.wav'
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
data,sample_rate = librosa.load(filename)
_ = librosa.display.waveplot(data,sr=sample_rate)
ipd.Audio(filename)
```

problem !!

> NoBackendError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 3 filename = 'C:/Users/adil/Desktop/PROJ 2/Udacity-ML-Capstone-master/UrbanSound Dataset
> sample/audio/103074-7-0-0.wav'
> 4 plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
> ----> 5 data,sample_rate = librosa.load(filename)
> 6 _ = librosa.display.waveplot(data,sr=sample_rate)
> 7 ipd.Audio(filename)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py in load(path, sr,
> mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
> 110
> 111     y = []
> --> 112     with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
> 113         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
> 114         n_channels = input_file.channels
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread_*init*_.py in
> audio_open(path, backends)
> 114
> 115     # All backends failed!
> --> 116     raise NoBackendError()
>
> NoBackendError:
>
> Figure size 864x288 with 0 Axes

Comment: What if you simply put `plt.figure(12,4)` ?

Comment: just for the dimension of graph, the error I think in 'data,sample_rate = librosa.load(filename)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the above problem by removing the:

```
data,sample_rate = librosa.load(filename)
```